# Change editor font of Android Studio per Mac?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying the new Android Studio for Mac but can't seem to be able to change font. I can only change the theme. For some reason the font change is disabled.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried here Android Studio > Preferences > (Under the heading "IDE Settings") Editor > Colors & Fonts

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Click the Save As... button on the top of the Font panel and enter a name on the dialog that pops up. This will be the name of your custom font Scheme.

You should be able to select fonts from the Available fonts list now.

Comment: rednull is right, the reason why you can't edit the font size is because you can't edit the default theme. What you need to do is press the "Save As..." button (this duplicates the current theme) and then customize it as much as you want (the 'Size' input will become editable).

Answer (score 5):

To change font goto `File` **=>** `Settings` (Shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>) **=>** from left panel choose `Editor` **=>** `Colors & Fonts` **=>** `Fonts`

**Updated Answer**

[image]

- Remove all fonts from right panel **(Selected fonts)** by double clicking.
- Now select font by double click from `Available fonts`
- Apply and Ok

Comment: Thanks Rstar, but as your screenshot shows, the font field is disabled.